# Penalty function method

Tags: python, math

I am trying to implement penalty function method for minimizing function. I need to find the minimum of [Rosenbrok's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenbrock_function).

I am using this penalty function:

[image: Penalty Function]

[image: Penalty Function]

First of all, I have found the minimum using `scipy.optimize.minimize`:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize, rosen
rz = lambda x: (1-x[0])**2 + 100*(x[1] - x[0]**2)**2;
h_1 = lambda x: (x[0] - 2 * x[1] + 2);
h_2 = lambda x: (-x[0] - 2 * x[1] + 6);
h_3 = lambda x: (-x[0] + 2 * x[1] + 2);

x0 = [2.3, 5];
cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': h_1},
       {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': h_2},
       {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': h_3}) 
minimize(rz, x0, constraints=cons)
```

The answer is `x`: `array([ 0.99971613,  0.99942073])`

Then I am trying to find the minimum using my implementation of penalty method:

```
x_c = [2.3, 3];
i = 1;
while i < 1000:
    curr_func = lambda x: rz(x) + i*(h_1(x)**2 + h_2(x)**2 + h_3(x)**2)
    x_c = minimize(curr_func, x_c).x;
    i  *= 1.2;
print(answer.x);
```

Which gives me `[ 2.27402022  1.4157964 ]` (if I increase the number of iterations, final values are even greater).

Where is the mistake in my implementation?
Thanks.

P.S. Function `curr_func` is specific for my constraints, of course, when they are all 'inequals' type.

Comment: Could you add some intermediate results and compare these with your expectations / knowledge of the algorithm?

Comment: The "penalty method" is a pretty general term and can refer to a few different things. It seems to me the most common usage is to refer to a method of enforcing constraints, which would correspond to the first term of your `Phi(x, a)`. I am not sure what the second term is for, but it would seem to me like you should be decreasing `i` for each iteration. Can you explain what you mean by the "penalty method"?

Comment: The formula I use is on the pictures in the question above. The main idea is to transform constrained optimization problem into unconstrained one. This can be done by minimizing the sequence of supportive functions `F(x, a)` (see picture above) where `a` is an increasing sequence (for instance eometric progression), and `x` is a point finded on the previous step. Accuracy is increasing with the number of iterations.

Comment: @MaxVorontsov Oh ok I understand what you're doing now. See answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you have is that the `h_i` in your formula are for *equality* constraints, whereas the problem you are solving is for *inequality* constraints, which correspond to the `g_i` in your formula. Hence, your penalty function should be using terms like `min(0, h_1(x))**2` instead of `h_1(x)**2`. To see why this is the case, just think about what happens if `i = 1000` and `x` is the desired solution `(1, 1)`. Then, the penalty will include a term `i * h_1(x)**2 = 1000`, which is huge.

Note that I used `min` instead of `max` because it seems like the inequality you want to enforce is `h_1(x) >= 0`. That means as long as `h_1(x) >= 0`, the penalty should be zero, but as soon as `h_1(x)` goes negative, you start penalizing. If it's actually `h_1(x) <= 0` you want, then you use `max` (then you'll have to switch `h_1` with `-h_1` when you use `scipy.optimize.minimize`).

BTW, since `i` is usually an index variable, it's probably better to name the penalty weight something else, like `a`.